# How to create form in yii using html tags (without using CHtml and CActiveForm widget

Tags: php, yii

i have form which is written in pure Html tags...

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/index.php?r=user/create'?>">
<div class="row">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username"/>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email"/>
</div>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
```

now i want to save data in database using my controller method **Create** and i also want to validate it first... i don't know how to do it....

i know how to do it using in CActiveForm and CHtml

i have model class generated using Gii... and my controller method is...

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->UserId));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Can anybody suggest me some startup code for that...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//controller
$request = Yii::app()->getRequest();
$model->username = $request->getPost('username');
$model->password = $request->getPost('password');
$model->save();
//view
if ($model->hasErrors('username')) {
   echo $model->getError('username');
}
```

Comment: now i am able to get this form data in controller but it's not validating my data... can you take look of my controller pastebin.com/vgaC4wfi

Comment: i am using $_POST to get all data.. is is fine or i shall do like you suggested.. bcz if i follow your answer then i have to get data for every element and that would be take time...

Answer (score 2):

```
public function actionCreate(){
 if(!empty($_POST)) print_r($_POST);
```

.....

and you will see where you were wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the 'name' with the **model class name** like:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/index.php?r=user/create'?>">
<div class="row">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="User[username]"/>
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="User[password]"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="User[email]"/>
</div>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks but in my case designing is done by some frontend dev... so i can't do this way... but now i am able to get this form data in controller but it's not validating my data... can you take look of my controller http://pastebin.com/vgaC4wfi